# SwiftUI vs StoryBoard ваше мнение

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Собственно вопрос тем, кто их использовал: что удобнее и практичнее? Плюсы и минусы?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Удобнее, конечно же, свифт юай.

Но больше возможностей на старой системе.

Скорость разработки юая значительно-значительно лучше именно на SwiftUI.

Другое дело, что есть ряд проблем:

1. СвифтЮай все еще сырой и недоработанный в плане функциональности. Очень много штук там недоступны из коробки. Часть доступного функционала на стадии "бета" недоступно в релизе. У тебя вряд ли выйдет использовать только коробочный функционал, прийдется дописывать.
2. Плохая обработка ошибок. Показывающийся ошибки - святой рандом. Так что нужно быть акуратным и постоянно помнить какие изменения ты вносишь. Оно будет показывать ошибки не только неправильные, но и в неправильных местах! ( все из-за отвратной работы икскода с лямбдами... А весь свифт-юай и построен на лямбдах )
3. СвифтЮай медленнее работает. Ну это логично. Плата за скорость разработки. Так всегда)
4. В идеале нужно знать и то и другое. На данный момент времени.
5. Как бы не нахваливали превьюшку (предпросмотр "без компиляции") свифтЮая - она глючная и не всегда работает корректно. Из того что могу наверняка сказать - хреново работает с светлой и темной темами. Бекграунд на противоположной теме от активной показывается в любом случае неправильно. Это и в первой и второй версии.
6. По-хорошему нужно разбираться с реактивным/функциональным программированием. В даном случае говориться о Combine, но вообще его можно заменить/дополнить чем-либо другим.
7. программа будет работать только на самых последних последней осях. А обновляются не все.

Про старую систему:

(+) Более функциональная

(+) Более быстрая

(+) работает на старых версиях ОС

(+) достаточно много информации и документации

(-) Более сложная

(-) Значительно медленнее разработка. Особенно Юая со всякими анимациями.

---

но при этом лично мой выбор - SwiftUI. За ним будущее.