# Что актуально: SwiftUI или Storyboard?

Tags: swiftui, storyboard

Изучаю самостоятельно iOS разработку. В основном все обучающие видео с использованием Storyboard, даже за последний год. По SwiftUI практически ничего нет, но как я понимаю, качественная работа считается именно на SwiftUI, а не Storyboard. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что лучше изучать(SwiftUI или Storyboard)? Или сначала Storyboard с помощью видео и уже самостоятельно переводить это на SwiftUI? Например, я не могу нигде найти видео, как работать с API в SwiftUI, но очень много информации в Storyboard. Значит мне нужно сначала понять как это работает в Storyboard, и потом самостоятельно сделать тоже самое в SwiftUI? Или сейчас просто все пишут приложения на Storyboard?

Answer (score 2):

SwiftUI очень молодой фреймворк и некоторые вещи пока просто невозможно сделать без UIKit (Storyboard это лишь малая часть).

Также SwiftUI доступен с iOS 13 (некоторые "вкусные" вещи только с iOS 14, а там и iOS 15 не за горами с новыми плюшками...), при этом, многим заказчикам нужна поддержка min iOS 12 и ниже. Что автоматически отбрасывает SwiftUI. Многие и с Objective-C не собираются переписывать.

Также обширная кодовая база наработок с UIKit. Никто не бросится сразу переписывать работающие, стабильные проекты на что-то новенькое только ради этого новенького, ещё и с перспективой поиметь кучу проблем из-за этого.

Поэтому сейчас SwiftUI хорош только в новых проектах, либо если окончательно принято решение обновлять старое. Всё зависит от проекта и заказчика.

Возможно, будет как и со Swift в свое время, что первые версии затягивали заядлые энтузиасты, страдая с миграциями на каждую новую версию. А после Swift 3 уже начался глобальный переход с Objective-C на Swift.

Answer (score 0):

Здесь я сравнивал в общих чертах и то и другое: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1055037/186752

Пока что изучая swiftUI тебе прийдется изучать и UIKit. Полный отказ от UIKit пока что невозможен. Да и сам swiftUI на даную секунду является оберткой над UIKit. (вполне вероятно что в будущем это изменится)

Что до того что нету информации как писать на swiftUI - я не согласен. Этой информации более чем полно. Вот прям реально много. Это и официальные туторы от эпл, и сайт https://www.hackingwithswift.com на который ведет большинство запросов по свифт юаю в гугле. И кучи блогов и ответов на англоязычный SO. Вобщем - не придумывай.

Мой совет - если ты новичек - изучай swiftUI как более простой вариант, а когда будешь сталкиватся с теми или иными проблемами - все равно прийдешь к тому что прийдется изучать заодно и UIKit.